# AzureMapsCodeSamples cannot run in local drive

Tags: azure, dictionary, shapefile

I download AzureMapsCodeSamples from [enter link description here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples) as zip file and unzip in my local drive, replaced primary key, and tried to get it run but failed. It seemed the data from the file of common couldn't be accessed...[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was fixed by myself. The links within .html files were not correct.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm very new to JS and struggling to understand how to run these examples locally. I have my subscription Id entered, so everything but the data are rendering. Thanks!